# windows Network Monitoring Tools

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

I am wanted to know how many computer accesses in a same internet in small office.  If any body know  any free  tools which can monitor small network (2 Windows PC's and 10 laptop mainly running XP - some Vista) and report how many computer attach in a same network.

Answer (score 2):

[PolyMon](http://www.codeplex.com/polymon) - free and open source monitoring application generally aimed at servers can monitor Windows Performance Monitor data, so you can monitor the actual health of the computers (Disk Queue's, Disk Usage, Memory Usage). Supports PowerShell monitors so you can monitor virtually anything you can interrogate with PowerShell. Plenty of notification options.

[SpiceWorks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) - free and advertising supported, monitors your network including various WMI counters allows you to report on the data gathered and send notifications when a warning level is reached.

I have used both, SpiceWorks doesn’t scale very well so I switched to using PolyMon which requires more configuration however is more flexible and scalable.

Comment: He doesn't need it to scale. Spiceworks, works great for a small-to-medium network. I <3 spiceworks.

Answer (score 0):

We use Lansweeper. Works well. http://www.lansweeper.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking for a tool to sweep your network and tell you how many 'nodes' (devices) are active right now, then [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Download) is about as simple as it gets. You feed it your network address range, and it tests every possible IP in that range to determine if it's alive.